# How can I use Python and pyodbc to print out table column names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a working script that connects to a SQL Database and then writes the query data to a `csv` file.

It looks like this:

```
mydb = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=gamerTest;"
                      "Database=rpg_games;"
                      "uid=x;pwd=x")

cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = """SELECT TOP (1000) *
  FROM [rpg_games].[dbo].[myGames]"""
cursor.execute(sql)

row = cursor.fetchall()

with open('testing_games_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    a.writerow(["My_Header_1", "My_Header_2"])  # how to automate?
    a.writerows(row)
```

I want the script to programatically print all the database table column names using `a.writerow` but I can't figure out how to do that or if that's even possible.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#cursor-attributes) says, you should look into `cursor.description`. It contains the column names, and other information.

Comment: I see the column reference but is that for writing out column names?  They don't really explain that part

Comment: I think you should get a list of tuples. You should just iterate the list, take the first item. Something like:

`[i[0] for i in cursor.description]` should work.